# How to connect Microsoft Graph to Azure Sql Database?

Tags: entity-framework-core, azure-functions, microsoft-graph-api, azure-sql-database, sharepoint-online

I’m working on an application that allows you to make a data exchange between Azure sql Database and Sharepoint Online using Azure Functions (Timer Trigger ) .
Really the first project in this environment ,I used Microsoft Graph to collect data from online sharepoint but didn’t really find a way to connect it with Azure Sql Database.My friend suggested me to try mapping data to Azure with Entity Framework Core but even with this solution I couldn’t transfer the data between them. I hope you can help me.

Comment: EF and transferring data is bad idea, it has nothing with performance in such case. Actually what you have tried to do?

Comment: I agree with @SvyatoslavDanyliv - it's bad design too and no perf improvements.

Comment: the project is to exchange data between sharepoint lists and azure sql using azure function timer trigger , you can suggest me a solution. Thanks

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv  any ideas ?? Thanks

Comment: @Dev any ideas ?? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box, Microsoft Graph does not provide you with APIs to work with Azure SQL Databases. Once you read the data from SharePoint Online using Microsoft Graph within your Azure Function, you might call Azure SQL Database directly from your Azure Function, similar to this:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scenario-database-table-cleanup

Comment: I used microsoft graph for retrieve data from sharepoint online because sharepoint api (csom) does not support netcore (only supports Net framework with which the azure function does not work well ) then if you have an idea about the things I have to work with this project tell me. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use MS Graph Connector to bring Azure SQL or MS SQL to SharePoint Online. Depends on [supported data types on SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftsearch/mssql-connector), you'll need to modify source data types to brining it into SharePoint Online.  This way, you can skip Azure Function, and use PnP Modern Search web parts to display data using MS Graph as data source. You can set how often to refresh source data.